# Custom project template with xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have been searching for topics related to custom project template creation with xcode 4.5. None have been appropriate and concise. Firstly I cant locate the default templates folder with xcode 4.5 and OS X 10.8 (guess it is hidden by default) and secondly , the steps to create a custom template from scratch is unavailable or I haven't searched effectively.

Kindly help, with my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [this link](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/xcode4-template-documentation/) you can download a good document to explain how create custom template with XCode.

Your post is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491826/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4)

To add your own template you need to go :

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/

and create the folder Templates if doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the link, i m looking into it and it has been very helpful. But I m not able to locate the project templates folder, where the default templates like single view app, master detail app are available with respect to xcode 4.5. Any idea , about its location?

Comment: Got the project template folder. Right clicking on xcode under applications and selecting show package contents takes me there..

Comment: so copy past the folder "Templates" here and it's good :)