# How can I change the default code generated when creating a new file in Xcode5?

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode5

I must be wording this funny because I can't even get close to a fruitful search.

When I create a new file through the graphical interface (right-click -> new file -> Objective-c class) I want my personal pragma marks to be stubbed out.

How can I specify a template for this in Xcode5?

I apologize if this is obvious or well documented already.

**EDIT** 11/18

To be more specific, I am not talking about project templates (Master-Detail, Tabbed Application, etc) but rather file templates. An example would be how new (Xcode generated) `UIViewController` subclasses come with some of the view lifecycle delegate methods like `viewDidLoad` and such. I would like control over that boilerplate/stubs are created on a per-file/subclasss basis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491826/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4 duplicate?

Comment: @juniperi, nope- I wish it was though, because that was a good answer. I'm looking for individual file templating. Like how a new view controller subclass will have `-(void)viewDidLoad` and things. I use a similar set of pragmas in every file, and I'd like to reduce my time typing that boilerplate.

Comment: Actually, while the answer detailed project templates, there was a link for file templating. I'll write up the answer I needed after I implement it.

Comment: did you end up finding out how to do file templating mate?