# Custom Xcode platform

Tags: xcode, sdk, clang, llvm, platform

I would like to create a custom platform for Xcode. A platform is a set of tools bundled in with an SDK for a specific target device and architecture.

When you press File -> New Project in Xcode, you see iOS and OS X. I would like my platform to appear there. When projects are created, they then have the correct build settings as well as target compiler and architecture specified.

I have copied the OSX.platform file and modified some of the values, but it ties into Apple defaults for the compiler and other settings. How can I specify these myself? Eg. The path to the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at gnustep http://www.gnustep.org/  and  cocotron http://www.cocotron.org/
Good luck.

Comment: This has nothing to do with platform creation. I don't see how they are relevant. Aren't they just cross-platform ports of the Cocoa Framework and supporting APIs?

Comment: Sorry,I misunderstood your question.  Is it the xcode template you are talking about?  If yes, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15491827/3132196

Comment: No. I'm not looking to make a template. I'm looking to make a platform. See my revised post.