# To use XCode for Perl Scripts

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode, bash, perl

Minimum Script for Practicing conversion of terminal scripts into Perl and using them finally in Xcode

```
use strict;
use warnings;

## Conversion of one-liner into Script by perl -MO=Deparse
# Original command: perl -ne 'print unless /[0-5]/' input.txt > output.txt
# I got the following command from: perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'print unless /[0-5]/'
# but also the notice: -e syntax OK
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_ unless
    /[0-5]/;
} input.txt > output.txt
```

I set settings as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092255/54964) about running Perl in Xcode .
However, I am unsure what I should have here in parameters. 
I set nothing there. 
I am so confused about this sentence:

> Go to the Arguments tab and ensure that your main script is the first
>   argument. Add more arguments and environment variables as necessary.

I run the script and get the following `0_dyld_start` message in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26001841/54964) but in Python

```
dyld`_dyld_start:
->  0x7fff5fc01000 <+0>:   popq   %rdi
    0x7fff5fc01001 <+1>:   pushq  $0x0
    0x7fff5fc01003 <+3>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff5fc01006 <+6>:   andq   $-0x10, %rsp
    0x7fff5fc0100a <+10>:  subq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x7fff5fc0100e <+14>:  movl   0x8(%rbp), %esi
    0x7fff5fc01011 <+17>:  leaq   0x10(%rbp), %rdx
    0x7fff5fc01015 <+21>:  movq   0x37aec(%rip), %r8        ; _dyld_start_static
    0x7fff5fc0101c <+28>:  leaq   -0x23(%rip), %rcx         ; <+0>
    0x7fff5fc01023 <+35>:  subq   %r8, %rcx
    0x7fff5fc01026 <+38>:  leaq   -0x102d(%rip), %r8
    0x7fff5fc0102d <+45>:  leaq   -0x8(%rbp), %r9
    0x7fff5fc01031 <+49>:  callq  0x7fff5fc01076            ; dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
    0x7fff5fc01036 <+54>:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff5fc0103a <+58>:  cmpq   $0x0, %rdi
    0x7fff5fc0103e <+62>:  jne    0x7fff5fc01050            ; <+80>
    0x7fff5fc01040 <+64>:  movq   %rbp, %rsp
    0x7fff5fc01043 <+67>:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
    0x7fff5fc01047 <+71>:  movq   $0x0, %rbp
    0x7fff5fc0104e <+78>:  jmpq   *%rax
    0x7fff5fc01050 <+80>:  addq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x7fff5fc01054 <+84>:  pushq  %rdi
    0x7fff5fc01055 <+85>:  movq   0x8(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff5fc01059 <+89>:  leaq   0x10(%rbp), %rsi
    0x7fff5fc0105d <+93>:  leaq   0x8(%rsi,%rdi,8), %rdx
    0x7fff5fc01062 <+98>:  movq   %rdx, %rcx
    0x7fff5fc01065 <+101>: movq   (%rcx), %r8
    0x7fff5fc01068 <+104>: addq   $0x8, %rcx
    0x7fff5fc0106c <+108>: testq  %r8, %r8
    0x7fff5fc0106f <+111>: jne    0x7fff5fc01065            ; <+101>
    0x7fff5fc01071 <+113>: jmpq   *%rax
    0x7fff5fc01073 <+115>: nop
```

In Info, I set `/usr/bin/perl` as described in the above thread. 
In Product > Scheme, I put disabled `XPC Services` and `View Debugging` (I think the latter one is for OSX tools debugging so disabled it).

How can you set correctly settings for Perl in XCode?
The most probably mistake is in setting arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove the 'v' from :

Product ->Scheme-> EditScheme -> Info -> and then remove the 'V' from the 'Debug Executable' box.