# Add warning dynamically to Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am asking my self if there are a way to add dynamic warning to my project.For exemple, every method in my class should begin by an analytics tag (setTagVorView:), if this line doesn't exists, I or other developers will be notified by a warning on this method.

Today, my only solution is to create a protocol (delegate) with a required method and every class (UIViewController for example) should follow this protocol and implements the required methods. The problem is : if the developer forgot the delegate, he will never be notified.

Another example, the [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) command line tool add warnings to the project if some properties or methods don't have descriptions.

So how can i add my rules to predict warnings in some cases ?

Thank you.

Comment: Obiter: did you consider a solution that doesn't require someone manually to adorn every method call and therefore doesn't need to generate warnings? Method swizzling or inserting a proxy would be the two most obvious ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSAssert`s in all the methods you want the developers to override:

```
NSAssert(NO, @"You need to implement this methode!");
```

It's, of course, not as elegant as compile time warnings.

Alternatively, you could create a XCode file template,with hardcoded warnings in. Take a look at this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491826/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fits your needs, but there is at least on way, hardcode way to achieve this goal: create a clang plugin and add there your own rules.

I'm not going very deep, because it might take too much time, but if you really interested in this solutions you can take a look at [this blog-post](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/02/28/creation-and-using-clang-plugin-with-xcode/), there is actually described a way to make the plugin with custom warnings and even errors