# Generate subclass method for override in .m file, like UIViewController's viewDidLoad

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to define a class such that Xcode will generate code for method overrides in subclasses?

For example, every time you subclass `UIViewController`, Xcode generates

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
- (void)viewDidLoad
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

inside the .m file.

Is there a way I can do this for my own subclasses? How would I do this, and what is this called?

Comment: You're looking to create a template file.

Comment: Question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491826/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4