# Creating Xcode 6 Custom Project Templates

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I would like to create a custom project template for the iOS in Xcode 6.  I thought it would be as easy as setting up your template, and File->ExportAs->CustomTemplate.  This would be INSANELY useful!  I find myself spending hours doing the same setup every time I start making a new iOS game.  But as I looked into the matter, I could find NOTHING on doing this on Xcode 6.

Either that, or is there a way to duplicate a current project with a different BundleID etc... So it would effectively do the same thing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491826/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4. It's basically the same with Xcode 6.

Comment: Github has an option to turn a repo into a template repo.  On the repo page, go to settings, and there is a checkbox to create a Template Repository.  I haven't messed with it yet, but it sounds like this could be very useful.  You'll still have to change everything specific to each project, like the name, bundleID etc.  But its a great start!